# How do I make Python 3.5 my default version on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have just installed Python 3.5.1 on my Mac (running the latest version of OSX). My system came with Python 2.7 installed. When I type `IDLE` at the Terminal prompt my system pulls up the original Python 2.7 rather than the newly installed Python 3.5. How do I get my system to default to Python 3.5.1 when I open the IDLE window from Terminal?

Comment: Some answers say uninstall it. If this works for OSX, great, enjoy. If you run Debian/Ubuntu removing Python2 will hose your machine as too many system components expect it to be there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Python 2 and 3 can happily coexist on the same system, you can easily switch between them by specifying in your commands when you want to use Python 3.

So for Idle, you need to type `idle3` in the terminal in order to use it with Python 3 and `idle` for using it with Python 2.

Similarly, if you need to run a script or reach a python prompt from the terminal you should type `python3` when you want to use Python 3 and `python` when you want to use Python 2.

Comment: Thank you very much. Typing idle3 at the terminal prompt was exactly what I was looking for. Sincerely, George

Answer (score 4):

It's good practice to have your MacOS Python environment set up properly from the beginning making sure that Homebrew installations take precedence over stock MacOS binaries. You want it in `usr/local/bin` not MacOS default `usr/bin`.

.bash_profile

```
# Ensure user-installed binaries take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# Load .bashrc if it exists
test -f ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Can also create aliases for both.

```
alias py2='python2.7'
alias py3='python3.6'
```

Source the file to ensure it takes effect for the current session

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Homebrew install and setup etc...

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew doctor
brew update
brew upgrade --all
brew cleanup
```

Python3 install

```
brew install python3
```

Next

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

Next

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

When all is finished `python3`, `pip3`, `virtualenv`, and `virtualenvwrapper.sh` will all be in `usr/local/bin`.

**Result**

Every time I install anything or use commands like `mkvirtualenv` Python 3 is used by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `python3` command (instead of using `python`), or you can simply uninstall the 2.7 version if you don't use it

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I am not clear on how to uninstall 2.7. Where would I use the python3 command. To access python in idle I just type idle at the terminal prompt.

Comment: Do not remove the Python2.7 that comes with OS-X. It depends on it.

Comment: The Mac OS needs Python 2.7 and you can't uninstall it. Maybe you can uninstall if the 2.7 was installed with `brew` or similar tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have any python 2 scripts that you use, you can delete python2. But its not a problem to have them both installed. You just have to use another path `python3` to launch IDLE.

I would prefer to let them both installled so if you have any scripts that are in python 2 you can still run them or you have to port them to python3.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. How do I use another path python3 to launch IDLE? Thanks, George

Comment: Because I have to use both for boring reasons `alias p2=/path/to/python2` and `alias p3`. in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` is both explicit and saves typing. I'm also fond of ipython so `ip2` and `ip3` are aliases also.

Comment: I don't understand you post. Would you please expand on your explanation. Thanks, George

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to any python version in your project by creating a virtual environment.

- virtualenv  -p /usr/bin/python2.x (or python 3.x)

In case you just want to run a program in a specific version just open shell and enter python2.x or python3.x

Answer (score 1):

Do right thing, do thing right!

1. Open your terminal,
2. input ***`python -V`***, It likely shows:**`Python 2.7.10`**
3. input ***`python3 -V`***, It likely shows:**`Python 3.7.2`**
4. input ***`where  python`*** or ***`which python`***, It likely shows:**`/usr/bin/python`**
5. input ***`where python3`*** or ***`which python3`***, It likely shows:
   **`/usr/local/bin/python3`**
6. add the following line at the bottom of your PATH environment variable file in **~/.profile** file or **~/.bash_profile** under Bash or **~/.zshrc** under zsh.

***`alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3'`***
OR
***`alias python=python3`***

7. input source **~/.bash_profile** under Bash or source **~/.zshrc** under zsh.
8. Quit the terminal.
9. Open your terminal, and input ***`python -V`***, It likely shows:
   **`Python 3.7.2`**

Note, the ~/.bash_profile under zsh is not that ~/.bash_profile.

The PATH environment variable under zsh instead ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_file) via ~/.zshrc.

Hope this helped you all!

Comment: Highlight the code and keep answer short and simple thank you

Answer (score 0):

By typing `python`, you are actually referring to a link.
You will find its location with `$ which python`. In my case it was `/usr/local/bin/python`. go there `$open /usr/local/bin/` and just delete the original python, python-config and idle as they are
identical to the 2.7 files in the same folder.
Then duplicate the 3.5 files and rename them to what you just deleted.

This also changes the default link other editors like Sublime_ReplPython use and updates it therefore to the 3.5 Version. This was my major concern with the standard installation.