# Installed Python 3.6.x packages for Mac, but "python" still starts 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to run Python 3 on my MacOS High Sierra. However, the official binaries for 3.6.3 and 3.6.2 once installed are actually running 2.7.10!

To be clear, these binaries:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/python-3.6.3-macosx10.6.pkg

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/python-3.6.2-macosx10.6.pkg

Are producing the following 2.7.10 output on my MacOS High Sierra:

```
$python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I actually uninstalled 3.6.3 before installing 3.6.2 and the results were precisely the same.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try the command `python3`, because by default you have python2 on your mac

Comment: Also you may have to add python3 to your path to be able to run the command without absolute path.

Comment: Please try to make question titles detailed and specific -- "Issue with Python binaries" doesn't really tell someone *anything* until they click through and read the text.

Comment: [How do I make Python 3.5 my default version on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528107/how-do-i-make-python-3-5-my-default-version-on-macos) is quite near to being a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Type `which python` to see the python in your path. It is probably not what you expect.

Also`python --version` will tell you the version of the app be being found in your path.

If this isn't what you expect you can use an absolute path to where there versions you refer to are actually installed.  Better still create a venv from the absolute path and activate it. This will properly construct the environment you want.

Hope that helps.